# how to write an Coldfusion if-clause that checks for a certain page?

Tags: coldfusion, if-statement

I'm trying to write a general COLDFUSION pageheader template, which I want to include on every page using

```
 <CFINCLUDE TEMPLATE="pageheader.cfm">
```

Inside the template I need to make some switches depending on the page I'm on. For example, I want to use **products.css** only on the *product.cfm* page.

As this is my first day with Coldfusion and I'm working from a demo which does not any page dependend-switches, can someone please tell me how I would set something like this up:

```
<CFIF I'm on page products.html>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="products.css" />
</CFIF>
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<cfif listlast(cgi.script_name,"/") EQ "product.cfm">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="products.css" />
</cfif>
```

Answer (score 2):

A better choice would be to use [cfhtmlhead](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ae9.html) on the products.cfm page.

```
<cfhtmlhead text='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="products.css" />'>
```

Comment: Cool. Why is it a better idea? Curious :-)

Comment: Well, if you eventually have a couple of pages needing a specific CSS file, you wind up with if ... else if ... else if ... in pageheader, which is clumsy. If you wind up renaming or moving your product.cfm page, you don't have to modify pageheader to match. It just seems to me to be bad form for a page to have to know it's caller for it to be able to do it's job right.

Comment: Ok. Got it. The CSS is one thing, but I needed a way to identify the page I'm on. Actually I'm only if-ing for the index.cfm page, all other pages get the same stuff. Still with my 1 day Coldfusion expierence... wasn't clear. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

This works fine too...

```
 <cfif #cgi.PATH_INFO# CONTAINS 'products.html'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="products.css"> 
 </cfif>
```